# What's the different between calling function with and without 'return' in recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I tried to create recursive function for generating Pascal's triangle as below.

```
    numRows = 5
    ans=[[1],[1,1]]
          
    def pascal(arr,pre,idx):
        if idx==numRows:
            return ans
           
        if len(arr)!=idx:
            for i in range (0,len(pre)-1,1):
                arr+=[pre[i]+pre[i+1]]
        
        if len(arr)==idx:
            arr+=[1]
            ans.append(arr)
            pascal([1],arr,idx+1)
        
    a = pascal([1],ans[1],2)
    return a
```

The output I got was an empty list `[ ]`. But if I add `return` when calling `pascal` as

```
            return pascal([1],arr,idx+1)
```

the output was correct `[[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1]]`.

As I understand, `a` should have been assigned by `return ans`. Then why `a` failed to get an answer when calling `pascal` without `return` and why `return` is necessary in this case?

Comment: return sends a value. No return is the same as `return None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have recursion, you usually combine the returns in some way. Could be a sum, like fibonacci:

```
fibonacci(n+1) = fibonnaci(n)+fibonacci(n-1)
```

Or appending a line to a matrix, like your case. Anyway, if you don't have a return, you have no information to combine! Consider the fibonnaci case without return:

```py
def fibonnaci(n):
  if n<2:
    return 1
  
  fib_ans = fibonnaci(n-2)+fibonnaci(n-1)
```

In this case, if I called `fibonnaci(0)` or `fibonnaci(1)` the output would be 1, like you return ans if idx == numRows, but if I called `fibonnaci(2)`, then the variable fib_ans would receive 2, which is the expected answer, but it would be available outside the scope of the funtion. Python "would add" `return None` to the end of my function, just below the fib_ans attribution. So, I need to return fib_ans

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as i know, if you want to get a value back you need the "return" statement...

The point is if you don't have "return", you will be getting no values back...

Hopefully this helps..

Answer (score 0):

For all algol languages that has a `return` keyword it exits the nearest function completely and the result of it is the result of the expression of the return argument. eg.

```
def test(v):
  if v == 0:
    return someFun(10)
  ...
```

If `v` is zero the result of the function is the value returned by `someFun(10)`. The rest of the function denoted by ... is never executed unless `v` is nonzero.

If we write the same without `return`:

```
def test(v):
  if v == 0:
    someFun(10)
  ...
```

Now, when `v` is zero `someFun(10)` is still called, but the value returned by it is **discarded** and in order for it to have any true meaning `someFun` needs to do some side effects, like printing, storing values, updating object. In addition all the rest of the function denoted by ... is then continued once `someFun(10)` is done.

For Python and many other languages not having a `return` at all doesn't mean it doesn't return anything. In Python there is an invisible `return None` in the last line of every function/method.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `pascal([1],arr,idx+1)`, you are doing the recursive call but then discarding the value which it returns.  If you want to return it to the caller, then you need to use explicitly `return pascal(...)`.

In fact recursion is not necessary in this example anyway. You could easily refactor your code to use a simple `for` loop. For example:

```
def pascal(numRows):
    ans = [[1]]
    for _ in range(1, numRows):
        pre = ans[-1]
        arr = [1]
        for i in range(0,len(pre)-1,1):
            arr+=[pre[i]+pre[i+1]]
        arr+=[1]
        ans.append(arr)
    return ans

print(pascal(5))
```

(I'm using the name `_` here as the `for` loop variable according to convention because it is a dummy variable not used inside the loop, but you could use something else e.g. `row` if you prefer.)

The above is as close to the original code as possible, but you should also consider using `arr.append(value)` in place of `arr += [value]` -- this would be the normal way to append a single value to a list.

Comment: Even though op wanted to do it recursively, this could be more efficient